# SwiperJS Smooth Transition with slideTo()

Tags: javascript, html, animation, swiper.js

I wondering if anybody can point me to the correct direction. I am implementing a SwiperJS slider that's similar to swiperJS virtual slides [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/9brhz2?file=/index.html) where the pagination is a text. However, in the demo, the click isn't smooth, but rather it jumps to the slides.

Is there a way to have that slideTo method have the same effect as a normal transition?

I've been reading the documention, but I could have missed something. Most of the samples have been dots. However, I did find this [sample](https://codepen.io/ncer/pen/xpqemZ) where `renderBullet` can be used, but mine is returning two sets of buttons. Still trying if this might work.
`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck

Comment: swiper.slideTo(index, `speed`, runCallbacks) - Run transition to the slide with index number equal to 'index' parameter for the duration equal to 'speed' parameter. https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#method-swiper-slideTo